# My code for Full Calendar works in Chrome, Firefox but why is this breaking in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, fullcalendar

This code works in Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari the calendar does not even load on the screen.

Basically I need to pull event data automatically from another website, and then feed it into Full Calendar. The format that the other website sends event details is an array with properties "name" and "time." Full Calendar takes event details in the form of an array called "events" with properties "title" and "start." So with the code below, I tried to rename the array and the properties to follow Full Calendar's format. And then inside the code rendering the calendar, I call that array "events". It works in Chrome and Firefox, but on Safari it does not and the console is telling me that it is expecting a ":" after property name "events"? How can I get this to work with Safari?

```
var getEvents = function() {

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",

            url: API_ENDPOINT,

            dataType: 'jsonp',

            success: displayEvents

            });

        };

var displayEvents = function(data) {

    var events = data.results;

    function changeData(events) {

        var start;

        for (var i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

            if (events[i].hasOwnProperty("name")) {
                events[i]["title"] = events[i]["name"];
                delete events[i]["name"];
            }

            if (events[i].hasOwnProperty("time")) {
                events[i]["start"] = events[i]["time"];
                delete events[i]["time"];
            }

            if (events[i].hasOwnProperty("start")) {
                start = events[i].start;
                events[i].start = new Date(start);
            }

        }

    }

    changeData(events);

    console.log(events);

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        events

    });

    }

getEvents();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ events });`

to `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ events: events });`

where the first `events` is the property name of the Object you're passing to the `$.fullCalendar()` function, and the second `events` is the value, ie your previously defined variable.